# Possible to restore calendar file from unit after update to 4.4.2?

Tags: updates, calendar, recovery-mode, restore

Is it possible to restore the calendar file from the unit's storage after update to 4.4.2? 
The file was in Android/data/com.android.calendar. And no, I had no backup of the file...  :-(

I've rooted the the phone (Samsung Galaxy S4) and tried numerous ways of recovering without any success. Please help me!!

Comment: Did you have (or do) a Google sync for Calendar via `System > Accounts`?

Comment: Nope, but I wish I had.  :-/

Comment: How did you update, though? OTA or Kies? Or did you flash a custom ROM, which may have wiped your data?

Comment: Just a plain OTA.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that the contacts stored on the unit are gone too. The 4.4.2 update seems to be a killer.

Comment: What version did you come from? 4.3? I had no idea OTA could clear data. Usually, I just flash stock/custom ROMs manually. [Sorry, I can't help you] So, Karan is right. You won't be able to restore it. Make sure to start using Google sync from now on. :)

Comment: Yepp, I came from 4.3. Guess if I have learnt a lesson... 
I usuallay back stuff up, but I didn't expect OTA to mess with the stored files.

Comment: It should have not deleted your data though. http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/11/21/the-nexus-4-finally-gets-4-4-heres-how-you-can-flash-the-kitkat-krt16s-ota-manually-root-or-unlock-not-required/

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't sync your Calendar with Google, I'm afraid you won't be able to restore it.